# How to Create Azure Servicebus Topic Custom Correlation Filter using the CLI

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-cli, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I am able to create a *system* properties correlation filter using this syntax:

```
az servicebus topic subscription rule create --name "rulename" --namespace-name "my-servicebus" --resource-group "my-rg" --subscription-name "mysub" --filter-type "CorrelationFilter" --topic-name "my-topic" --label="my-value"
```

What is the CLI syntax for creating a correlation filter using a *custom* key value pair? (As in the section under "CUSTOM PROPERTIES" in the GUI.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I did it is to revert back to the REST API calling the Management endpint, https://management.azure.com/

Since doign this, there may be a "native" CLI way to do it, but the REST API technique works fine so we have left it as it is.

Answer (score 1):

```
az servicebus topic subscription rule create --name <rulename> --namespace-name <servicebusname> resource-group <rg-name> --subscription-name <subscription-name> --topic-name <topic> --filter-type CorrelationFilter --correlation-filter key01="MyLabel"
```

This creates custom property with key "key01" and value "MyLabel"

Comment: This worked as expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the CLI source code [`here`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/16026226fb2e9746f65d53afcac4bf708bbd279f/src/azure-cli/azure/cli/command_modules/servicebus/custom.py#L479), you just have to specify all the attributes related to a correlation filter in your CLI command.

```
if filter_type == 'CorrelationFilter':
    parameters.correlation_filter = CorrelationFilter(
        correlation_id=correlation_id,
        to=to,
        message_id=message_id,
        reply_to=reply_to,
        label=label,
        session_id=session_id,
        reply_to_session_id=reply_to_session_id,
        content_type=content_type,
        requires_preprocessing=requires_preprocessing)
```

Something like:

```
az servicebus topic subscription rule create --name "rulename" --namespace-name "my-servicebus" --resource-group "my-rg" --subscription-name "mysub" --filter-type "CorrelationFilter" --topic-name "my-topic" --label="my-value" --correlation-id="something" --to="something"....
```

Comment: Doesn't work. As per the OP, using --label="my-value" just creates a system based correlation filter, not custom one.